# How to write type declarations to hide specific properties from typescript hints?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Bear with me, I have some 'dense' code.

Here is a class, the functions inside are designed to be chainable

```
interface EncoderResult {
  result: string | number
  finish(): string | number
}

interface Ascii extends EncoderResult {
  toAscii<T extends UniversalEncoder>(
    this: T,
    chars?: string
  ): Omit<T, 'toAscii'>
}

interface Base64 extends EncoderResult {
  toBase64<T>(this: T): Omit<T, 'toBase64'>
}

type UniversalEncoder = Ascii & Base64

class Encoder implements UniversalEncoder {
  result!: string | number

  toAscii<T extends Omit<UniversalEncoder, 'toAscii'>>(
    this: T,
    chars?: string
  ): Omit<T, 'toAscii'> {
    this.result = chars
    return this
  }

  toBase64<T>(this: T): Omit<T, 'toBase64'> {
    return this
  }

  finish() {
    return this.result
  }
}
```

However, **finish()** and **result** shouldn't be available such scenario:

```
const encoder = new Encoder()
encoder.finish()
encoder.result
```

These properties are meaningless in such early state

How to write type declarations to hide them from typescript hints?

**Expecting:**

```
encoder.finish() // Error: property 'finish' does not exist on type ~
encoder.toAscii().result // Error: property 'result' does not exist on type ~
encoder.toAscii().toAscii() // Not allowed
encoder.toAscii().finish() // expected
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code to remove typos such as `finsish` and invalid code such as `implements UniversalEncoder`.... and anything that warns you when you run in `--strict` mode, like trying to assign `undefined` to `string | number`, or not initializing your properties. You might want to test this in an IDE like [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to be sure.  The goal is to make it so that only your actual problems are on display, not issues that distract from them.  (You probably also don't need so many generics in this code, could you trim it to a [mre]?)

Comment: Fundamentally, if `finish` (and `result`?) shouldn't be available from `encoder` until `toAscii` is called (etc.), then `finish` shouldn't be on the `encoder` object at all. It should be on a different object *returned* by `toAscii` (etc.).

Comment: Wow, there are a *lot* of edits happening here, every few seconds, and each one still seems to have scads of errors in my IDE.  I'm going to unfollow this now and come back later to see if it has stabilized and demonstrates a true [mre] we can work on.  Good luck!

Comment: I am reading your comments. hold on

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Enw) what you're looking for? I chopped out a lot of stuff with generics; if it isn't what you're looking for could you demonstrate what's missing? But if it is what you're looking for then I could write up an answer explaining.

Comment: Yes! Thank you sir, probably I need more practice on typescript, my appologize for any inconvience

Comment: Since you've already written up an answer does that mean you don't need me to write one?  Or would you still want me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you simply can NOT achieve this.  This is not how programming is done.  Any IDE "doesn't remember" what is your previous line of code is doing.  It's would allow you to type all accessible properties and methods of the class. IDE would just handle compile time error before any program is run.  Since below code will be compiled, IDE cannot hide the hints to use those method and properties.

```
let encoder = new Encoder()
encoder.finish()
encoder.result
```

Obviously, it would produce produce run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

I've fully undertand this, now the code is:

```
class Encoder {
  private result!: string | number

  toAscii() {
    return {
      toBinary: () => this.toBinary(),
      toAscii: () => this.toAscii(),
      toBase64: () => this.toBase64(),
      finish: () => this.#finish()
    }
  }

  toBinary() {
    return {
      toBinary: () => this.toBinary(),
      toAscii: () => this.toAscii(),
      toBase64: () => this.toBase64(),
      finish: () => this.#finish()
    }
  }

  toBase64() {
    return {
      toBinary: () => this.toBinary(),
      toAscii: () => this.toAscii(),
      finish: () => this.#finish()
    }
  }

  #finish() {
    return this.result
  }
}

new Encoder().toAscii()
```

It looks dumb, but clear, I would like to optimize it later.

Big appologize to the community.